# Joy (as noun)+ gerund

Tags: present-participles

> ### joy noun (SUCCESS)
>
> › [U] UK informal ​success, ​action, or ​help:
>   [+ -ing verb] Did you have any **joy ​finding** that ​book you ​wanted?
>   We ​tried ​asking ​local ​libraries for ​information, but got no joy from any of them.

I noticed that the dictionary says that the word in question can take "ing" after it. How is this possible that a noun can take a verb which follows it? Are we supposed to treat "finding" as present participle which modifies the whole sentence? Like "Did you have any joy (while or in) finding that book you wanted?

Comment: It seems to be similar to "luck" or "success". Any problem with these two?

Answer (score 2):

In BrE usage, **joy** has a meaning similar to **success** or **luck** in AmE usage.

> Were you **able to** ?
>   Were you **successful** with ?
>   Anything **positive** happen ?

can be asked by Brits by simply using

> **Any joy ?**

an American would ask

> **Any luck ?**

Whereas an American saying

> He got **no joy** finding a new car

would mean

> he had **no enjoyment** in searching for a new car

for a Brit, it would mean

> he was **unsuccessful**

**Joy** like **luck** is something you can **get**, however it is not something **lost**, nor is it **bad**
From my experience, it is primarily used by the **English**